# Where can Carmichael Function be applied?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question

I know that Carmichael function written usually as $\lambda(n)$ is defined like this:$$\lambda(2) = 1\\\lambda(4) = 2\\\lambda(2^k) = 2^{k-2}\\\lambda(p^k)=p^{k-1}(p-1)\\\lambda(n) = lcm [\lambda(p_1^{\alpha_1}),\lambda(p_2^{\alpha_2}),...,\lambda(p_r^{\alpha_r})]\text{ for }n = p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}...p_r^{\alpha_r}$$
I also noticed that Carmichael theorem ($a^{\lambda(n)} \equiv 1$ (mod n)) gives a huge improvement of Eulers theorem but are there other uses of it?

Comment: For example, there is a nice way to classify the Carmichael numbers : A composite number $N$ is a Carmichael number if and only if $N\equiv 1\mod \lambda(N)$. Which applications exactly do you have in mind ?

Comment: Has it been used in some known problems and can you give me an example of carmichael numbers being used

Comment: A carmichael number is a composite number $N$ with the property that $a^{N-1}\equiv 1\mod N$ holds for every $a$ coprime to $N$. The smallest such number is $561$. We have $\lambda(561)=80$, and because of $561\equiv 1\mod 80$ we can conclude that $561$ must be either a prime or a carmichael number. Since $561$ is divisible by $3$, we can conclude that it is a Carmichael number.

Comment: A famous trick which determines the $5$ th root of a number of the form $n^5$, where $n$ is a $2$-digit number is based on the fact that $n^5\equiv n\mod 10$ is true for all integers $n$. This can be shown easily with the Carmichael function and the cycle-property.

Comment: Really neat , now I can imagine i lt being used in various cases